# Set PATH for one command in fish

Tags: fish

In bash in order to update PATH just for one command I can do:

```
env PATH=/my/path:$PATH mycommand.sh
```

What is the equivalent syntax for fish? I have tried many variations with spaces or colons, and none work.

Comment: Wrong place for this. StackOverflow is for programming questions. Maybe ask on SuperUser or the Unix StackExchange...

Comment: @DavidMakogon fish shell *is* a programming language. Why not go and downvote all questions marked with this tag then?

Comment: @DavidMakogon, fish questions are fine here. I used to think vim questions were off-topic too. There are tolerant sub-communities to support the smaller languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fish, $PATH is a **list** not a colon-separated string. You need to convert it to the expected format first:

```
env PATH=(string join ":" /my/path $PATH) mycommand.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! That's ridiculously verbose though, shame that there's no shorter option.

Comment: "ridiculously"? You have lofty standards my friend